# In Numpy, how to use an array of items as the guide to determine the index of items in a second array?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

This is hard to describe with a good title. Here is what I want to do:

I have a numpy array with unique items in it:

```
unique_arr = np.asarray([1, 4, 12, 5])
```

...then I have a second array that is very long, and has many occurrences of the items in the first array:

```
long_arr = np.asarray([12, 4, 4, 1, 12, 5, 5, ... ])
```

I'd like to make a third array that is the same length of `long_arr`, but instead of the items `long_arr` has, it has the indexes of those items in `unique_arr`:

```
long_idxs =  something_magic(unique_arr, long_arr)
print(long_idxs)
>>> [2, 1, 1, 0, 2, 3, 3, ...]
```

Is there an efficient numpy-way of accomplishing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `searchsorted`, but then you need to sort `unique_arr` first:

```
unique, idx = np.unique(unique_arr, return_index=True)

a = np.searchsorted(unique, long_arr)

long_idxs = idx[a]
```

Output:

```
array([2, 1, 1, 0, 2, 3, 3])
```

Note that `searchsorted` doesn't check for exact match, e.g. if `long_arr` contains `3`, it would returns `1` still. You may need to validate the result.